# How can I update google talk client for Windows?

Tags: updates, google-talk

I want to update my Google talk client, but I don't see an option to do that in the tool.  I can't even find the version number!  Is it automatically updated or do I just need to download the installer again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Google Talk has just 2 editions - the [standard edition](http://www.google.com/talk/) and [the Labs edition](http://www.google.com/talk/labsedition/index.html)

Both haven't been updated since quite some time.

Comment: Which I'm really sad about, I really like the app.